Difficulty in connecting Dlink Wifi Extender(N300 Wi-Fi Range Extender DAP-1325) with Ubuntu 24.04
Problem
Difficulty in connecting Dlink WiFi Extender
Observations

Extender works fine when :

Phone,tablet,windows PC
On Ubuntu 19.04
On Ubuntu 24.04 when:

Ipv4 and Ipv6 are disabled
Ipv4 and Ipv6 methods are in local mode
Initial setup of Wifi Extender

(All above cases On Ubuntu 24.04 when internet connectivity is not available)




Extender doesn't works when :
when Configs are not changed (On Ubuntu 24.04). it tries to connect the WiFi but fails eventually.


when i tried following command to connect
nmcli device wifi connect <SSID> password <password>

I've got the following error message.
Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.).

Initial Inference
Some config changes happened during the transitioning of Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 20 series (ie : to snap packages). That affected the connectivity to the WiFi extender.
I hope you got the clear picture. Please help me solve the problem :)

Please see this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1517871/difficulty-in-connecting-tp-link-wifi-extender-with-ubuntu-24-04/1517918#1517918

Hi thanks for responding. unfortunately the solution you provided doesn't work in my case.
